# Select an Option from the Right-Click Menu in Selenium Webdriver - Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium webdriver. I am not able to select (say 2nd) option from the Options opened on right click.

In my current code I am able to right click on webElement but could not select an Option from the list that is opened after right click, as it disappears automatically.

```
Actions action= new Actions(driver);
action.contextClick(productLink).build().perform();
```

So with this code I am able to right click but the right click menu automatically disappears. I want to select say 2nd Option from Right click menu.

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To select the item from  the contextual menu, you have to just move your mouse positions with the use of Key down event like this:-

```
Actions action= new Actions(driver);
action.contextClick(productLink).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();
```

hope this will works for you. 
Have a great day :)

Comment: Didnt work for me I tried the following 
       Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
       builder.contextClick(element)
       .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
       .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
       .sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)
       .build().perform();
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       driver.close();

Comment: Doesn't work for me either

Answer (score 10):

*Using Robot class you can do this, Try following code:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.contextClick(WebElement).build().perform();
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

**[UPDATE]**

**CAUTION:** Your Browser should always be in focus i.e. running in foreground while performing Robot Actions, other-wise any other application in foreground will receive the actions.

Answer (score 9):

this is better approach and its successful :

```
Actions oAction = new Actions(driver);
oAction.moveToElement(Webelement);
oAction.contextClick(Webelement).build().perform();  /* this will perform right click */
WebElement elementOpen = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Open")); /*This will select menu after right click */

elementOpen.click();
```

Comment: works maybe for custom menus but not for Chrome browser menu

Answer (score 5):

We will take the help of WebDriver action class and perform Right Click. the below is the syntax :

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver).contextClick(element);
action.build().perform();
```

Below are the Steps we have followed in the example:

1. Identify the element
2. Wait for the presence of Element
3. Now perform Context click
4. After that we need to select the required link.

package com.pack.rightclick;

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
    import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
    import org.testng.Assert;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class RightClickExample {

    WebDriver driver;

    String URL = "http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html";

    @BeforeClass
    public void Setup() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test
    public void rightClickTest() {
        driver.navigate().to(URL);
        By locator = By.cssSelector(".context-menu-one.box");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator)); 
        WebElement element=driver.findElement(locator);
        rightClick(element);
        WebElement elementEdit =driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".context-menu-item.icon.icon-edit>span"));
        elementEdit.click();
        Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
        String textEdit = alert.getText();
        Assert.assertEquals(textEdit, "clicked: edit", "Failed to click on Edit link");
    }

    public void rightClick(WebElement element) {
        try {
            Actions action = new Actions(driver).contextClick(element);
            action.build().perform();

            System.out.println("Sucessfully Right clicked on the element");
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            System.out.println("Element is not attached to the page document "
                    + e.getStackTrace());
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("Element " + element + " was not found in DOM "
                    + e.getStackTrace());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Element " + element + " was not clickable "
                    + e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }


}
```

Comment: What would be the css locator for "Save link as..."?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of attempting to do a right click on a mouse use the keyboard shortcut:

Double click on the element -> hold shift and press F10.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

//Hold left shift and press F10
action.MoveToElement(element).DoubleClick().KeyDown(Keys.LeftShift).SendKeys(Keys.F10).KeyUp(Keys.LeftShift).Build().Perform();
```

Comment: "Double click on the element -> hold shift and press F10." Helped me!!

Answer (score 1):

You might have to move the mouse to any particular location after context click() like this -

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
actions.contextClick(link).moveByOffset(x,y).click().build().perform();
```

To understand how moveByOffset(x,y) works look [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#moveByOffset%28int,%20int%29);

I hope this works. You will have to calculate the offset values for **x** and **y**;

best way would be to find the size of each option button after right clicking and then if you click on the 2nd option .

x = **width of option button**/2

y = 2*(**size of each option button**)

Comment: @ Hari Reddy - Thanks for answering, In current solution problem is that i am Not able to get the offset values because "Right Click Menu options" cannot be inspected in firebug. So Not able to get the offsets in Firebug> layout.

Comment: yes I understand your problem. Even I'm not sure how we can find the width of the options we get after right click. Can you try some hit and trail way, try incrementing by 5 or 10. Let me know what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Right click can be achieved using Java script executor as well(in cases where action class is not supported):

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

String javaScript = "var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');"
                + "var RIGHT_CLICK_BUTTON_CODE = 2;"
                + "evt.initMouseEvent('contextmenu', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, RIGHT_CLICK_BUTTON_CODE, null);"
                + "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evt)";

js.executeScript(javaScript, element);
```

Answer (score 1):

Better and easy way.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href^='https://www.amazon.in/ap/signin']"))).contextClick().build().perform();
```

You can use any selector at the place of `cssSelector`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for Right click on a webelement.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);    
Action action=actions.contextClick(WebElement).build(); //pass WebElement as an argument
            action.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i could click on the fourth element in the `Right click window`.

```
 Actions myAction = new Actions(driver); 
 myAction.contextClick(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li[1]/a/img"))).build().perform();
 myAction.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).build().perform();
 myAction.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).build().perform();
 myAction.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).build().perform();
 myAction.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).build().perform();
 myAction.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Using python webdriver right click operation

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html")
button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[@class='wy-body-for-nav']")

action=ActionChains(driver)
action.context_click(button).perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement xx = driver.findElement(By.linkText("your element"));
                Actions action = new Actions(driver);
                System.out.println("To open new tab");
                  action.contextClick(xx).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
                    Robot robot = new Robot();
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```