# Right click in selenium webdriver problems

Tags: scala, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've found this code here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22376627/4165083

```
Actions oAction = new Actions(driver);
oAction.moveToElement(Webelement);
oAction.contextClick(Webelement).build().perform();  /* this will perform right click */
WebElement elementOpen = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Open")); /*This will select menu after right click */

elementOpen.click();
```

But I'm having problems with driver: "Cannot resolve symbol driver". I can't import anything. What should I do to get it working in my tests in Scala?

Comment: Is `elementOpen ` the element you are trying to perform right click on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Cannot resolve symbol driver" - Check have you created the instance of the WebDriver and is accessible.

For Actions class - import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
Provide complete code to assist.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referencing to wrong element. You have to reference to the element you are trying to right click on;

```
WebElement elementToRightClickOn = driver.findElement(By.id("something"));
Actions oAction = new Actions(driver);
oAction.moveToElement(elementToRightClickOn);
oAction.contextClick(elementToRightClickOn).build().perform();  /* this will perform right click */
WebElement elementOpen = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Open")); /*This will select menu after right click */

elementOpen.click();
```

Comment: Alright, the problem was a little different that that with the "Cannot resolve symbol driver" but now, with similar code, I can't get "Actions" to create.

I get: Cannot resolve constructor Actions. Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you instantiated the `driver` properly? Like  `driver = new ChromeDriver();` or something before