# Testing Chrome Extension with Context Menu

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I am working on a Chrome Add On that adds context menu items using [`chrome.contextMenus`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus).

I am looking to create some tests as I develop the extension to ensure proper functionality. I have looked into using Selenium and similar, but there does not seem to be the concept of interacting with the "system" context menu, only context menus which are actually JavaScript called by intercepting right clicking. The solutions for the browser's real context menu seem a bit hacky.

I am starting to look at things like autohotkey and AutoIt, but I am not sure that these are the best tools out there for this type of testing since Chrome doesn't use native Windows controls.

I see there is some work with AutoIt *[Chrome UDF](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/154439-chrome-udf/)*, but I wanted to check if there was a purpose built tool that can consistently interact with the browser. I also want to check that other tabs are open, etc.

---

I have read [How do I test a context menu entry in a Chrome Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37373741/how-do-i-test-a-context-menu-entry-in-a-chrome-extension) -> [Select an Option from the Right-Click Menu in Selenium Webdriver - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428026/select-an-option-from-the-right-click-menu-in-selenium-webdriver-java) , but I am not sure how this would work if you don't know which menu items might be present from other extensions or customizations.

Comment: You can interact with context menus, using java robot class also, but the only limitation is your browser needs to be in focus all the time, so the key events target is always your browser.

Comment: There's a contextMenu sample on [this github](https://github.com/orbitbot/chrome-extensions-examples/tree/master/basic_2)

Comment: No, that link doesnt contain any tests