# Selenium right click scrolling down before selecting options

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've seen this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428026/select-an-option-from-the-right-click-menu-in-selenium-webdriver-java) and when I try to use `sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)` instead of moving down the context menu the page scrolls down very quickly. How can I avoid this? I'm not sure how to wait for a context menu to appear, though I can wait for an element to be present.

Here's the function:

```
    public static void rightClickCopyImageLink(WebElement image){
    Actions copying = new Actions(driver);

    copying.contextClick(image).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).
    sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).
    sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();

}
```

Comment: Could you share your code with us?

Comment: Sure, not very complicated code just learning selenium

Comment: Mmm, I'm sorry I don't see anything wrong with your code nor can I reproduce it.

Comment: Bummer. It's really odd, everywhere I look no one seems to have this problem, but my code is completely the same as theirs. I can reproduce the same behavior in my browser just by right clicking and pressing the down arrow at the same exact time, but that doesn't really help other than demonstrating the problem.

Comment: try updating selenium to latest version..

Comment: The fact that you can do it in your browser yourself makes me think it's a browser specific issue. What browser/version are you using?

Comment: @RemcoW I'm using the current version of chrome with the current chromedriver

Comment: @Ranjith's I'm using the current 2.53.0 version

Comment: try downgrading the versions..

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **contextClick** separately from other actions.

```
copying.contextClick(image).build().perform();
copying.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).
sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).
sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();
```

If you want you can add wait until the context menu appears after **contextClick** action performed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that was the first thing I tried. Does the same exact thing, however.

Comment: I will add a wait and see if that works. Tips on the cleanest way to do so? Is there something other than time that I can make it wait for?

Comment: Then the control is not on the context menu. Try manually on the application how it is behaving if you press down arrow after context click. If it is working as expected then you should wait until context menu is appears and get the control or some how make context menu get the control.

Comment: It depends Alex. If context menu got any properties like id, name, etc. you can get that object and wait until it is displayed. I don't prefer using Thread. But in worst case you can use it. But first try with Thread and see it is working.

Comment: If I do it manually it works fine, as long as I don't press the down arrow instantly after the right click button.

Comment: Then it should work with actions as well. Because with actions you have to perform the same actions what you are doing manually

Comment: What am I doing wrong here, any idea?       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
This line is between the contextClick call and the sendKeys call(s)

Comment: I forced it to wait with Thread, at which point the down arrow still brought the page down.. Very odd. If I mouse right click and press the down arrow I immediately move down the contextmenu, NOT down the page.

Answer (score 0):

At first be sure that the image element is located correctly...

I assume on right click some submenus appear, do right click with seperate action chain.
Then Wait for the element to appear.

Once it appears just move to element and press down arrow.

Skeleton code may be :

```
public static void rightClickCopyImageLink(WebElement image){
        Actions rightClick= new Actions(driver);
        rightClick.contextClick(image).build().perform();
        //Wait for submenu to appear waituntil(submenu to be located)
        //Move to located submenu <this is important>

        Actions MoveDownSubmenu = new Actions(driver);
    MoveToRightClickSubmenu.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).build().perform();


    }
```

Comment: I've tried your implementation with splitting between two Actions, doesn't work either. Thanks for the idea though. Any other thoughts?

Comment: That's not the issue. I've got it tracked down now-it's a problem with the chrome webdriver....https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1003

Comment: If ur issue is still not resolved, try with AWT Robot key event it will definitely work but I would not recommend it since they are native events......use key press and release events once u moved to the submenu..

Comment: The problem is the chrome driver doesn't let you move to the submenu. It opens it but no matter what you do (including clicking, pressing escape, etc) you remain unable to move into the submenu. It's a chromedriver bug

Comment: yes I understand what you are saying, but the event I pointed out is not a webdriver event , It is a native event (someting like generated by your OS) It has nothing to do with Selenium. It is like manual Keypress while web driver is running.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html