# typing menu key or application key in selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to pass the menu key or application key ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key ) in Selenium, and due to some policy restrictions, I am not able to use the right click action to open the the dropdown menu.  (IE: `action.ContextClick(element)` does not work).

There is not an option I see for the menu button in `Keys.___`, nor was I able to find an alternative after searching.  Does anyone know how to access this menu without actually right clicking?

Comment: @JeffC my question is not about the Windows Key, but the key that sits in between Alt and Ctrl key at the right hand side of a keyboard ( you can click on the wikipedia link that I have provided ). I have searched for an answer in the many portals and also in SO, but I couldn't find it out, thats why I have reached out to the community. I am not able to use right click due to restrictions, but clicking on the menu key is bringing up the required window.

Comment: You are right. I even looked at the article but it looked like the Windows key to me so I assumed it was the same. Keys like the Windows and menu keys are not really individual keys but key combinations. In the article you linked they show 2 or 3 key combinations. Have you tried those? Please explain in more detail why you can't use right-click. Also post the code you have tried and any error messages or why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem before, and the menu key functionality is [not supported yet in selenium](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4296).

What you can do however is in the language of you shoice, the equivalent of 
`driver.SendKeys(Keys.Shift + Keys.F10);` (Shift + F10 is an equivalent to the menu key), and then follow the [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11450187/8206275) for navigating menus using actions and mouse position movements.