# How to right click and hold it in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web, automation

I'm looking to automate my web browser to rotate a map created using mapbox, however this can only be done by holding the right mouse down and panning around.

I know there is a click and hold option for the left click, but is there anything similar for right click? At present I can only do a single right click using context click

Comment: I hope this can answer your query. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428026/select-an-option-from-the-right-click-menu-in-selenium-webdriver-java)

Comment: Unfortunately not! I need the right click to stay held down whilst I pan around

Comment: You can use `TouchActions` like `touchAc = TouchActions(driver)
touchAc.tap_and_hold(100, 700).scroll(100, 800).perform()`

Comment: That doesn't right click sadly

Comment: `actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.context_click(element).perform()` You can right click using this.

Comment: Its holding the right click which is my struggle. Similar to click_and_hold, I'm wondering if theres anything along the lines of context_and_hold

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not supported, but you can modify the source code of selenium in your site-packages directory, it's pretty straightforward since all you have to do is change the parameter for the pointer event in the click_and_hold method, to the same parameter as the pointer event in the context_click method, and then create a custom function for that.

Here's what I managed to do:

File 1: Locate and edit this file in
**Lib/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/actions/pointer_actions.py**

Add this function to the "PointerActions" class:

```py
class PointerActions(Interaction):
    def move_to_location(self, x, y):
        ...
    def click(self, element=None):
        ...
    def context_click(self, element=None):
        ...

    # --- Add this function
    def context_click_and_hold(self, element=None):
        if element:
            self.move_to(element)
        self.pointer_down(MouseButton.RIGHT)
        return self
    # ---
    
    def click_and_hold(self, element=None):
        ...

    def release(self):
        ...
    def double_click(self, element=None):
        ...
```

File 2: Locate and edit this file in
**Lib/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py**

Add this function to the "ActionChains" class:

```py
class ActionChains(object):
    def __init__(self, driver, duration=250):
        ...
    def click(self, on_element=None):
        ...

    # --- Add this function
    def context_click_and_hold(self, on_element=None):
        if on_element:
            self.move_to_element(on_element)

        self.w3c_actions.pointer_action.context_click_and_hold()
        self.w3c_actions.key_action.pause()

        return self
    # ---
    
    def click_and_hold(self, on_element=None):
        ...
    def context_click(self, on_element=None):
        ...
```

If the .release() function is not able to release the right mouse button after holding, you should add a parameter to the .release() function by making these changes:

```py
class PointerActions(Interaction):
    def click_and_hold(self):
        ...

    def release(self, button="left"):
        button = MouseButton.LEFT if button == "left" else MouseButton.RIGHT
        self.pointer_up(button)
        return self

    def double_click(self):
        ...
```

```py
class ActionChains(object):
    def pause(self):
        ...

    def release(self, button="left", on_element=None):
        """
        Releasing a held mouse button on an element.

        :Args:
         - on_element: The element to mouse up.
           If None, releases on current mouse position.
        """
        if on_element:
            self.move_to_element(on_element)

        self.w3c_actions.pointer_action.release(button)
        self.w3c_actions.key_action.pause()

        return self

    def send_keys(self):
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I have to add, that also need to change release function in action_chains.py. I just created right_release() function, that do the same, but with right button.