# Click Save button in VBA using Windows API

Tags: excel, vba, winapi

I am doing some scraping using excel vba and at some point I need to save the webpage of a specific content.
I am trying to simulate the `Save As` window using Windows API in excel VBA and I could change the file name field so as to have the desired path

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessageByString Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Dim strBuff As String, butCap As String
Public Const WM_SETTEXT = &HC
Public Const BM_CLICK = &HF5
```

And this is the code I am using till now

```
Sub Sample(sPic As String)
    'Dim hw As Long, hw2 As Long, hw3 As Long, saveRet As Long
     Dim hw As Long, hw2 As Long, hw3 As Long, hw4 As Long, hw5 As Long, hw6 As Long, sv As Long, saveRet As Long
     
    hw = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Save As")
    hw2 = FindWindowEx(hw, 0&, "DUIViewWndClassName", vbNullString)
    hw3 = FindWindowEx(hw2, 0&, "DirectUIHWND", vbNullString)
    hw4 = FindWindowEx(hw3, 0&, "FloatNotifySink", vbNullString)
    hw5 = FindWindowEx(hw4, 0&, "ComboBox", vbNullString)
    hw6 = FindWindowEx(hw5, 0&, "Edit", vbNullString)
    
    ' Set the file name
    Call SendMessageByString(hw6, &HC, 0, ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sPic & ".html")
    
    ' Click the Save button
    saveRet = FindWindowEx(hw, 0, "Button", "&Save")
    Call SendMessage(saveRet, BM_CLICK, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

This line works well `Call SendMessageByString(hw6, &HC, 0, ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sPic & ".html")` and I can get the whole path in the file name field and also the save button at this line `Call SendMessage(saveRet, BM_CLICK, 0, 0)` works well but when saving I didn't get my desired path but the default path.

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: To simulate the `Save As` window and specify the desired path.

Comment: You're not simulating it, you're trying to alter it after it's been displayed. What I'm asking is why?

Comment: To be able to change the save folder from `Downloads` folder to my desired folder.

Comment: My question really is why do you need to hijack the native SaveAs dialog at all, when there are other, simpler, methods in Excel VBA to ask for a save location

Comment: See https://excelchamps.com/vba/save-workbook/

Comment: I am dealing with selenium vba and this is kind of scraping and saving some html webpages. If there are any simpler approaches, I welcome to your ideas.

Comment: Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75864679/

Comment: Would have saved some time if you'd specified that to start with. Your question appeared, to me at least, to suggest it was the Excel dialog you were trying to manipulate.

Comment: @YasserKahlil Maybe in the https://github.com/GCuser99/SeleniumVBA project they have implemented saving a complete HTML document to a file.  I haven't kept up for a couple of months, so not sure offhand.